# android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, navigation

Есть стандартная разметка Navigation Drawer

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_tools">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.test.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/Activity"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_section1"
        android:name="com.example.test.ui.send.SendFragment"
        android:label="@string/section1"
        tools:layout="@layout/test" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.example.test.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/section2"
        tools:layout="@layout/test" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:name="com.example.test.ui.tools.ToolsFragment"
        android:label="@string/setting"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tools" />

</navigation>
```

Не могу понять, как управлять вот этим пунктом из кода

> app:startDestination="@+id/nav_tools"

Хочу чтобы при опеределенных условиях, при запуске стартовый фрагмент изменился.
Подскажите саму команду, как изменять её.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызовите этот код в onCreate вашей Activity

```
val navHostFragment = home_nav_fragment as NavHostFragment
val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_main)
graph.setDefaultArguments(intent.extras)
graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment1
//or
//graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment2

navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

Comment: Спасибо! Нужна была Java, всё нашел)

Answer (score 1):

Если кому то пригодится, код на Java

```
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavHostFragment navHost = (NavHostFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController = navHost.getNavController();

    NavInflater navInflater = navController.getNavInflater();
    NavGraph graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.mobile_navigation);
    graph.setStartDestination(activityToResume);
    //graph.setStartDestination(R.id.nav_gallery);
    navController.setGraph(graph);
```